# 'Cannot cast Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-core, json.net

I am working on a project and I am new to c#,
I cant figure out this problem
Below is the complete class

```
public class ApexJson
{
    public JObject Json;

    public ApexJson()
    {
        this.Json = new JObject();
    }

    public JProperty Set(string name, object content)
    {
        var prop = new JProperty(name, content);
        this.Json.Add(name, JValue.FromObject(content));
        return prop;
    }

    public T Get<T>(string name)
    {
        try
        {
            T prop = Json.Value<T>(name);

            return prop;
        }
        catch
        {
            return default(T);
        }
    }

    public NameValueCollection GetNv(string name)
    {
        return Get<NameValueCollection>(name);

    }
}
```

and This  function giving the error of 'Cannot cast Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken

```
public T Get<T>(string name)
{
    try
    {
        T prop = Json.Value<T>(name);

        return prop;
    }
    catch
    {
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

What will be the possible solution?

Comment: Please add [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and/or json which fails for you. But it seems that you have json array (i.e. something like `"[ {'prop':1}, {'prop':2} ]"` or just `[ 1,2,3,4 ]`) for the property with `name` - it can't be turned into `NameValueCollection`.

Comment: can you guide which changes i need to do in code?

Comment: It is very hard to do so without all needed code and actual task, but first recommendation is not to call `GetNv` for array properties.

Answer (score 1):

Hello and welcome to the C#.

The error seems not to be in the showed code.

Using your class, if I run this :

```
            ApexJson a = new ApexJson();
            a.Set("foo", 42);
            Console.WriteLine(a.Get<int>("foo"));
```

I get that :

```
42
```

I fact, if if I run this :

```
            ApexJson a = new ApexJson();
            a.Set("foo", new JArray(42));
            Console.WriteLine(a.Get<JToken>("foo"));
```

I get that :

```
[
  42
]
```

I assume you are doing something nasty in the part of code you don't show